# Generating IMA(1,1) series

Tags: time-series, simulation, arima

I'd like to generate a series that follows an IMA(1,1) process, where $θ$ is the moving average parameter. I generated the series based on different representations and I got different results, I'm wondering which one is correct?
$$
\begin{aligned}
d_1 &=μ+e_1  \\
d_t &=d_{t−1}−θ\cdot e_{t−1}+e_t  \\  \\
\text{or}  \\  \\
d_1 &=e_1  \\
d_t &=μ+d_{t−1}−θ\cdot e_{t−1}+e_t
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: 2)  d1=e(1); dt=μ+d(t−1)−θ*e1(t−1)+e1(t) is correct for simulation purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It is depending on which series you are actually looking at. Assuming $ \{ e_t\}$ is white noise.

In your first series,$d_1=\mu +e_1; d_t=d_{t−1} − \theta*e_{t−1} + e_t$, the series $d_t$ will have shift 
and 
in the second series, $d_1=e_1; d_t=\mu+d_{t−1}−\theta* e_{t−1} +e_t$, the series $d_t$ will have drift.

Both are IMA(1,1) series (for simulation purpose)

Comment: Actually if we suppose we have n periods, in the first one the constant part is equal to μ while in the second one equals to nμ

Comment: You are right. But still 1) and 2) are IMA series. The second series will have drift (you could find the term 'drift' in random walk literature).

Comment: Which one is more appropriate in practice? I don't knwo which one I should use for demand process simulation.

Comment: I guess the first one (I assume the periods are not very long and no linear growth in demand.)

Comment: Is it the same for the other process like MA(1), AR(1) , ARMA(1,1)?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Are you asking about the constants? MA(1) AR(1) ARMA(1,1) are stationary series.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7155/discussion-between-vinux-and-roji)